# rails object expected got string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I have seen multiple questions similar to this, but none worked for me.

I have a team model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :p1, :class_name => "Player", :foreign_key => 'player_id', :validate => true
  has_one :p2, :class_name => "Player", :foreign_key => 'player_id', :validate => true
end
```

in my team's _form.html.erb, I am referring to players as

```
  <%= f.collection_select :p1, Player.all, :id, :name %>
```

However, on form submission, I see the error:

```
Player(#28401456) expected, got String(#14111904)

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/teams_controller.rb:47:in `new'
```

---

```
Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"GSIcEvROFnvgGWT4HvE2VNqRw4NxU1J8iAw/WhZeRLk=",
 "team"=>{"p1"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create Team"}
```

And here is the code at line

```
def create
  @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  .....
end
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, this worked:

```
 <%= f.collection_select :p1_id, Player.all, :id, :name %>
```

Here is the magic:
My migration has t.references p1 and that created a column of p1_id in the database. 
When The form is submitted, rails is looking to fill in the id of the reference at:

```
def create
  @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  .....
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this - very misleading error message - should have told us the column-name didn't match any, and would have been a 20-sec fix instead of an hour.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this one. This also works with strong params in rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :player_id, Player.all, :id, :name %>
```

Comment: hmm, I see the following error: NoMethodError in Teams#new

Showing track/app/views/teams/_form.html.erb where line #14 raised:

undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol
Extracted source (around line #14):

11:     </div>
12:   <% end %>
13: 
14:   <%= f.collection_select :p1, :player_id, Player.all, :id, :name %>
15:   <!-- <%= f.select :p1, Player.all.collect { |e| [e.name, e.id] } %> -->
16: 
17:   <div class="actions">

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but my guess is that instead of

```
<%= f.collection_select :p1, Player.all, :id, :name %>
```

you need

```
<%= f.collection_select :p1, :team_id, Player.all, :id, :name %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: I see the error:  NoMethodError in Teams#new Showing track/app/views/teams/_form.html.erb where line #14 raised: undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol Extracted source (around line #14): 11: </div> 12: <% end %> 13: 14: <%= f.collection_select :p1, :id, Player.all, :id, :name %> 15: <!-- <%= f.select :p1, Player.all.collect { |e| [e.name, e.id] } %> --> 16: 17: <div class="actions">

Comment: Sorry, my original answer was wrong. I updated it. Try again?

Comment: hmm, back to square one. This is generating p1[team_id], what I want is team[p1].. Essentially the above is resulting in wrong behavior. I had to switch to my original form `<%= f.collection_select :p1, Player.all, :id, :name %>` as team comes automatically from f. However this brings me back to the original issue I posted :(