# rails object expected got string in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :p1, :class_name => "Player", :foreign_key => 'player_id', :validate => true
end
```

When i try to create a new record by using `Result.new` it throws `Result(#203425120) expected, got String(#127815260)`.

I seen most of the related questions..But they given only select sql based. Not creating new records.. Any comments would be appreciated..

Comment: Show your result's `_form.html.erb` where you are referring to players?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have `p1_id` in the database instead of just `p1`.

So, When you are referring to players, you should use the

```
<%= f.collection_select :p1_id, Player.all, :id, :name %>
```

Referred from:

[rails object expected got string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668281/rails-object-expected-got-string)

Comment: I am not using html.erb file. I am using Result.new in rake file. (to feed some data to DB)

Comment: If you do that without rake (programatically), then also you will get this problem. The problem is with your id either with association or elsewhere. Show your model associations and files.